# How to connect cached entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework but I've cached some application wide entities, so now they're List rather than entities.

Two of the objects I've cached are Products and Stores - a Product has a store. In a table they are linked by StoreId, but since I'm using EF the Product can also include the Store entity.

I don't cache them together simply because they are also used independently. What I would like to do is join them at some point, so I might subselect the Product object then want to populate Stores by joining the Stores object.

Is the most efficient way of joining 2 lists using linq - if so whats the most efficient syntax, or is there's a better way converting lists back to entities.

Comment: Why would a product know at which store it is sold? Also joining data from two table is only effective if there is an overlap in data. I don't see how stores and products have overlapping data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a better way of converting lists back to entities

This is a bit misleading as this isn't what your trying to do. You pull down a list of Products/Stores which are entities - no need to convert them (even if your storing them in a list).

If I understand you correctly what you want to do is basically map each `Product` to it's appropriate `Store` from the cached entities (to save going back to the DB by accessing the `Store` property on the `Product` entity). I am pretty sure all you need to do is map this across, so something like:

```
foreach (var product in cachedProducts)
{
    product.Store = cachedStores.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == product.StoreId);
}
```

Comment: You're correct. My current thinking is to get, the separate entities, ditch the context and use cache to store them. When its time to use them they need to be sync'd as a single object because a product is never displayed without its store.

Comment: If you ditch the context used to pull down the entities then when you go to save them you will simply have to re-attach them to the new context.

Answer (score 1):

Your entities are connected via the underlying database context, so removing them from this context prevents you from joining them back later or even saving them without attaching context.

the most efficient design is to use EF's IQueryable syntax to retrieve them whenever you need them and let the database context do any caching required / possible.

Comment: Yes, but as I pointed out, I cache these objects because they are application wide and so have a long lifespan. Are you saying keep the context open idenfinitely?

Comment: Ah yes I see now, I thought you had a requirement for entities, but you only want IEnumerable - it is as James said